# Jquery $().click not working with flask

Tags: jquery, flask

Got a little flask web app, trying to use **jquery** `$().click()` but it just isn't executing? No syntax errors, all files loaded, 0 errors of any sort in the web console or flask command line log.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login_form_container">
            <form id="login_form" method="post">
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="text" class="login_input" name="username" label="username" required></li>
                    <li><input type="password" class="login_input" name="password" label="password" required></li>
                    <li><input type="button" id="login_submit"></li>
                    <li><p class="errors"></p></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        <div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login_sumbit').click(function() {
        alert("click");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS you are using the selector `login_sumbit` while the button has the ID of `login_submit`. Simple typo here.